# How to configure nginx to point to specific domain sites to serve up content?

Tags: nginx

Essentially, I'm trying to serve up some content located at `http://local.pubsite.ed/samples/sample01.html` with nginx.

In order to do so, the directions to the repo instruct to:

```
Use your host file to set this host pointer for two local websites. 
You will need webserver on your system for your environment. 
If you don't have IIS or Apache available, try nginx. 
Webserver configuration is beyond scope of this document.

local.digitru.st 127.0.0.1 local.pubsite.ed 127.0.0.1

Point your webserver and both sites to the root of your source repository. 
Access your site samples at:

http://local.pubsite.ed/samples/sample01.html
```

I've pointed the nginx `root` variable, inside of `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, to the root of my local repository `/Users/zackcarlson/Desktop/Git/dt-cdn/`. However, that did not yield anything.

So I ended up deleting/uninstalling nginx and starting over following [this guide](https://medium.com/@ThomasTan/installing-nginx-in-mac-os-x-maverick-with-homebrew-d8867b7e8a5a).

I'd appreciate some guidance on how to proceed getting this thing to work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: that tutorial should be enough to get you started. Change `server_name` with `server_name local.pubsite.ed local.digitru.st` and make sure your `root` directive is correct. Restart nginx and that should be it. If not, please share with us your config, your errors form the log and a more detailed description of what's going on after you did these changes.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to work. I'm getting a `403 Forbidden` error. This is how my [nginx.conf looks (pt1)](https://ibb.co/SKryFys) and [nginx.conf (pt2)](https://ibb.co/hRftTrt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the following config to be working with the code from [DigiTrust repo](https://github.com/digi-trust/dt-cdn)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name local.pubsite.ed local.digitru.st
    index index.html;
    access_log logs/access.log combined;
    error_log logs/error.log error;

    location / {
        root /Users/zackcarlson/Desktop/Git/dt-cdn/;
    }
}
```

I can confirm this works, take a look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOZe8.jpg)

However, this is just the start for that project. To get it working, i had to:

1. clone the repo
2. follow [this doc](https://github.com/digi-trust/dt-cdn/blob/master/README_development.md) and run the `yarn` commands in order.

`grunt` command did not worked for me for some reason.

Hope this helps